# C deadlock detecting threading library

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, deadlock

In the past I remember seeing a threading library for C which did deadlock detection.  I can't remember what it was called, and I am spectacularly failing to find the right combination of terms to make Google tell me.

What I remember is this:

- It has a non-pthreads API. It takes advantage of restricting the API to be able to limit the cases it had to care about.
- It's a library you link in, not an external tool like Helgrind (although something's telling me it might have used valgrind code internally?  Possibly a red herring).
- It was written by a relatively familiar name, but I can't remember who.
- It has a couple of different execution modes so you could linearise lock sequences in different ways.
- It is open source.

Can anyone tell me what I'm thinking of?

Comment: Apart from the offtopicness of this question, why do you need a deadlock-detector?  On the rare occasions I have managed to screw up my code to get a deadlock, I have always found it pretty obvious which threads have got stuck.

Comment: I guess we can't all be perfect.

Comment: I'm not 'perfect', just puzzled...

Answer (score 1):

pthread_mutex_t types are:
PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL  no deadlock detection relocking causes a deadlock
PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK - returns an error on trying to relock
PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE - queues multiple lock requests (lock count) for a given mutex.

This pertains to pthread_mutex_lock, pthread_mutex_unlock, and pthread_mutex_trylock.

I would guess this is where you saw a deadlock discussion.  Other kinds of deadlock - ex: mutually excluding two threads from two resources by waiting on each others locks  - are not detected.  Programmers are meant to detect them.

I agree this is an odd question

see:  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html

Comment: "Other kinds of deadlock - ex: mutually excluding two threads from two resources by waiting on each others locks - are not detected."  That's the sort of deadlock detection I mean.  Again, I'm *not* thinking of pthreads.